# Rewrite under exists

Tags: coq

Say I have the following relation:

```
Inductive my_relation: nat -> Prop :=
constr n: my_relation n.
```

and I want to prove the following:

```
Lemma example:
  (forall n, my_relation n -> my_relation (S n)) -> (exists n, my_relation n) -> exists n, my_relation (S n).
Proof.
  intros.
```

After introducing, I have the following environment:

```
1 subgoal
H : forall n : nat, my_relation n -> my_relation (S n)
H0 : exists n : nat, my_relation n
______________________________________(1/1)
exists n : nat, my_relation (S n)
```

My question is: is there a possibility to rewrite H under the exists quantifier ? If not, is there a strategy to solve this kind of problem (this particular one is not really relevant, but problems where you have to prove an `exists` using another `exists`, and where, informally, you can « deduce » a way to rewrite the `exists` in the hypothesis into the `exists` in the goal) ?

For instance, if I try `rewrite H in H0.` I have, an error (`Error: Cannot find a relation to rewrite.`).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The standard way to manipulate an existential quantification in an hypothesis is to get a witness of the property using `inversion` or, better and simpler, `destruct`.

You can give a name to the variable using one of the following syntaxes:

```
destruct H0 as (n, H0).
destruct H0 as [n H0].
destruct H0 as (n & H0).
```

Note that you can also destruct an hypothesis using [intro-patterns](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/tactics.html#sec364).

```
intros H (n & H0).
```

And you can even directly apply `H` in `H0`.

```
intros H (n & H0%H). exists n. assumption.
```

[Software Foundations](https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/lf-current/Logic.html#lab175) explains this in a clear way.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way, I post it here for any similar questions in the future.

It is possible to inverse the `exists` hypothesis, in order to "instantiate" the quantified variable, for instance, here, the proof can be finished by:

```
  inversion H0.
  apply H in H1.
  exists x.
  apply H1.
Qed.
```

After `inversion H0`, we have in the environment:

```
1 subgoal
H : forall n : nat, my_relation n -> my_relation (S n)
H0 : exists n : nat, my_relation n
x : nat
H1 : my_relation x
______________________________________(1/1)
exists n : nat, my_relation (S n)
```

and we can now work with `x`.

Comment: I just found a way to solve, but I don't know the underlying mecanics, if you have any additional comments, dont' hesitate to edit.